# What is wrong with this shell script line?

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell var called $JOB_COMMAND that has the command to launch a map reduce job like so:

```
user@server:/scriptpath# echo $JOB_COMMAND
/var/elastic-mapreduce/elastic-mapreduce --create 
    --name 'Extrabux-MapReduce' 
    --num-instances 16 --instance-type c1.medium --key-pair extrabux-keypair 
    --log-uri s3n://extrabux-log/
    --bootstrap-action "s3://extrabux-scripts/startup.sh" |
    egrep -o 'j-[a-zA-Z0-9]+'
```

Obviously lots of those options are not needed for the point of the question, but in some off chance the content affects the answer, it's included.

Now when I try to run the command from the variable, I get this:

```
user@server:/scriptpath# $JOB_COMMAND
Error: --output must follow one of --streaming
```

However if I copy and paste the result of echoing the command like so I get the following:

```
user@server:/scriptpath#  /var/elastic-mapreduce/elastic-mapreduce --create 
    --name 'Extrabux-MapReduce' 
    --num-instances 16 --instance-type c1.medium --key-pair extrabux-keypair 
    --log-uri s3n://extrabux-log/
    --bootstrap-action "s3://extrabux-scripts/startup.sh" |
    egrep -o 'j-[a-zA-Z0-9]+'

j-3FV0MT3H7G21S
```

As you can see, the command runs and successfully spits out a job id

Here is what I would like to do, get the job ID into another shell var:

```
user@server:/scriptpath# JOBID=`$JOB_COMMAND`
```

Any idea why running the command when it is inside a var is breaking?
FYI, I have also tried

```
user@server:/scriptpath# JOBID=$($JOB_COMMAND)
```

and that also gives me the error

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the parsing of the pipeline (the `|` in your example) happens before the variable `$JOB_COMMAND` is expanded. In Bash, parsing the line happens first, then variables are expanded, split based on `$IFS`, and substituted into the commands. So in your command, the `| egrep` and everything following it are being passed as literal arguments to your `elastic-mapreduce` command; the error about `--output` is probably due to the `-o` argument.

As the [Bash FAQ](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) points out, you shouldn't be storing commands in variables, you should use [shell functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Shell-Functions) instead.

```
job_command () {
    /var/elastic-mapreduce/elastic-mapreduce --create \
        --name 'Extrabux-MapReduce' \
        --num-instances 16 --instance-type c1.medium --key-pair extrabux-keypair \
        --log-uri s3n://extrabux-log/ \
        --bootstrap-action "s3://extrabux-scripts/startup.sh" | \
        egrep -o 'j-[a-zA-Z0-9]+'
}
```

And now you can call it as follows:

```
JOBID=$(job_command)
```

Using shell functions would also allow you to pass parameters in to your command, which you may find to be useful.

If you really want to store a command in a variable for some reason, you will need to use [`eval`](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#index-eval-112), but this is not recommended:

```
eval $JOB_COMMAND
```

Answer (score 2):

Pipes don't work that way. Split it into two commands. Oh, and [BASH FAQ entry #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score 0):

Will be much readable (and functional) if

```
RESULT=`$JOB_COMMAND $JOB_ARGS | egrep ....`
```

Comment: That may break if an argument in the JOB_ARGS string contains embedded spaces. Better would be to store the args in an array, then `result=$( $command "${args[@]}" | egrep ...)`